# Redirects from angularjs or express

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I have an app where I need to redirect on login depending if the person has been authenticated using Passportjs.

Should I be redirecting using angularjs or express? It seems the latter is more secure being server side?

Hope someone can assist?

Regards

Comment: Check out the example app for M.E.A.N. http://mean.io/ look at /config/routes.js to see how they tie it in.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter *how* you redirect, it matters *why* you redirect.  *Why* should be because the **server** can't authenticate the user, which means the server can either notify the client to redirect or it can handle the operation itself if your app infrastructure allows for it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am going down the angularjs route but i have tried $location for the route redirect. So basically the user is authenticated by passportjs on the server and a response is sent. If successful then it needs to redirect to /admin/users page. How is this possible?